# Google cloud pubsub - Turning off pubsub for different environments

Tags: configuration, mocking, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

Maybe this is not the right approach (open to ideas), but I want to turn off pubsub for some testing environments if it's not necessary.

Note: I'm not trying to use a fake pubsub service (pubsub emulator), but I want the web app to not publish/subscribe to anything without putting a check for a flag like `isPubsubEnabled` everywhere.

I was thinking of just stubbing out the methods, so in node.js

```
this.pubsub = new NoOpPubsub();
this.pubsub.topic('my-topic').publisher().publish(my-message); // no-op and no error
```

Any ideas? Is what I'm doing a bad one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing sounds like implementation of a fake (albeit a minimal functionality one).  There is nothing wrong with this approach, although I would suggest if these are unit tests to use a mock instead like [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) so that you can check that the values you would otherwise be publishing to pubsub are correct.

If you are considering implementing a fake for a long-running environment, perhaps running the [pubsub emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) would be the best move, as it would give you somewhat realistic results given network request overhead, batching and other conditions as well as propagating your messages to subscribers in the same test environment.  But again, this is very much a decision about what's best for your use case.  If you just want to test all the other functionality absent pubsub, just having a NoOp fake would work.

Comment: For a long-running environment, using a pubsub emulator sounds like an interesting idea. I like the idea of being able to inspect what is being published. I'm not using it for unit testing--it feels weird to use a mock during normal runtime, but maybe it's better to do that than reinvent the wheel. However, it's not so hard in javascript/typescript to write some fake stuff.